# Objects data are not diaplayed on expanding on PL SQL Developer 8

Tags: plsqldeveloper

i have upgrade from PL SQL developer version 7 to 8 but I am not able to select any objects from left side drop downs like tables,indexes etc. when try to expand them they dont show any details.

I have selected current user and all objects

Comment: Some oracle web gui even restricts visibility for the current users to edit objects who they own too. Please check it before you look for options. That is configured by/through admin console.